# How to create new table rows by onclick?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know how to insert new table rows via an on click in JavaScript. At the bottom of the table, there is a row including a textbox for each column. This row contains a "Create" button, which should create a table row, before last row of the table. In addition, if you type some text into the textboxes and then click on the "Create" button, the text should be transferred into the columns of the new created row.
Each newcreated row must include two buttons. The first button called, "Change color" changes the color of the entire table row and second button "Delete" deletes the entire table row.
I don't know how to assign a new color for each new row to the function on click "change color". Could someone support me that every row gets various colors? I also don't know how to insert a table row, before last row of the table. The buttons "Change color" and "Delete row" are also not functioning.

You can find my Code here: https://jsfiddle.net/NoahSchwarz/j5mtsrbn/2/#&togetherjs=NuUS0LxnsH

```
HTML:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table</title>
    <style>
        table {
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
        tr {
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
        td {
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
    </style>
    <script defer src="myScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="table">
        <tr>
            <td class="cellrow1">Simon</td>
            <td class="cellrow1">Kolsch</td>
            <td class="cellrow1">SimonK</td>
            <td class="cellrow1">
                <button type="button" onclick="changecolor('cellrow1','color')">Change 
                color</button>
            </td>
            <td class="cellrow1">
                <button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete row</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="cellrow2">Noah</td>
            <td class="cellrow2">Schwarz</td>
            <td class="cellrow2">NoahS</td>
            <td class="cellrow2">
                <button type="button" onclick="changecolor('cellrow2','color')">Change 
                color</button>
            </td>
            <td class="cellrow2">
                <button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete row</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="cellrow3">Lukas</td>
            <td class="cellrow3">Ortlieb</td>
            <td class="cellrow3">OrLiLu</td>
            <td class="cellrow3">
                <button type="button" onclick="changecolor('cellrow3','color')">Change 
                color</button>
            </td>
            <td class="cellrow3">
                <button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete row</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="cellrow4">
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td class="cellrow4">
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td class="cellrow4">
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td class="cellrow4">
                <button type="button" onclick="addRow()">Create new Tablerow</button>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

```
JavaScript:

// Delete function (Deletes a whole Tablerow onclick)
function deleteRow(r) {
 var rows = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
 document.getElementById("table").deleteRow(rows);
}

// Color function (Colors a whole Tablerow onclick)
function changecolor(classesOfCellrows, color) {
 var cellrows = document.getElementsByClassName(classesOfCellrows);
 [...cellrows].forEach(rows => rows.style.backgroundColor = color);
 [...cellrows].forEach(element => console.log(element));
}

//This function will add a new row and everything that was typed into the 
//input field should then be transfered into the new Tablerow if created
function addRow() {
 var table = document.getElementById('table');
 var row = table.insertRow(0);
 var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
 var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
 var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
 var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
 var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
 cell4.innerHTML = "<button onclick= '//function'>Change color</button>";
 cell5.innerHTML = "<button onclick='//function'>Delete row</button>";
}
```

Comment: Please try to fix only one problem at a time - is there anything not working with the process to add new rows? If yes, please share more details

Comment: Hello. Yes there is a problem when I try to add new tablerows to my existing table. Every time I press the "Create new Tablerows" button, a new Tablerow should appear from the fourth row of the table. This in turn should contain the buttons "Change color" and "Delete row". The button "Change color" should change the color of the whole tablerow and the button "Delete row" should delete the whole tablerow.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. You should not only explain what you want, but also what you've tried to make it work, and where you are stuck

Comment: I added more clarificaiton to my question :)

Comment: So, what exactly is missing? Coloring the rows differently? What **exactly** is not working with that?

Comment: Yes, coloring the rows differently and deleting the rows isn't working properly. There are two buttons in each row. One is called "Change color" and the second button is called "Delete row". The button "Change color" changes the color of the whole row and the button "Delete row" deletes the whole row. Each button has an onclick function with parameters, except the button "Create row" at the bottom of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table</title>
    <style>
        table {
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
        tr {
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
        td {
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function deleteRow(r) {
            var rows = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
            document.getElementById("table").deleteRow(rows);
        }

        // Color function (Colors a whole Tablerow onclick)
        function changecolor(target, color) {
            target.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = color;
        }

        //This function will add a new row and everything that was typed into the
        //input field should then be transfered into the new Tablerow if created
        function addRow() {
            const lastRow = document.getElementById('table').rows[table.rows.length - 1];
            const row = document.createElement('tr');

            row.innerHTML = `
                <td>${lastRow.cells[0].children[0].value}</td>
                <td>${lastRow.cells[1].children[0].value}</td>
                <td>${lastRow.cells[2].children[0].value}</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" onclick="changecolor(this, 'red')">Change color</button>
                </td>
                <td class="cellrow1">
                    <button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete row</button>
                </td>
            `;
            table.rows[table.rows.length - 1].insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', row);

            //. initialize inputs
            lastRow.cells[0].children[0].value = lastRow.cells[1].children[0].value = lastRow.cells[2].children[0].value = '';
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td>Simon</td>
        <td>Kolsch</td>
        <td>SimonK</td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" onclick="changecolor(this,'red')">Change
                color</button>
        </td>
        <td class="cellrow1">
            <button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete row</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellrow2">Noah</td>
        <td class="cellrow2">Schwarz</td>
        <td class="cellrow2">NoahS</td>
        <td class="cellrow2">
            <button type="button" onclick="changecolor(this,'red')">Change
                color</button>
        </td>
        <td class="cellrow2">
            <button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete row</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellrow3">Lukas</td>
        <td class="cellrow3">Ortlieb</td>
        <td class="cellrow3">OrLiLu</td>
        <td class="cellrow3">
            <button type="button" onclick="changecolor(this,'red')">Change
                color</button>
        </td>
        <td class="cellrow3">
            <button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete row</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellrow4">
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td class="cellrow4">
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td class="cellrow4">
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td class="cellrow4">
            <button type="button" onclick="addRow()">Create new Tablerow</button>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

```js
function deleteRow(r) {
            var rows = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
            document.getElementById("table").deleteRow(rows);
        }

        // Color function (Colors a whole Tablerow onclick)
        function changecolor(target, color) {
            target.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = color;
        }

        //This function will add a new row and everything that was typed into the
        //input field should then be transfered into the new Tablerow if created
        function addRow() {
            const lastRow = document.getElementById('table').rows[table.rows.length - 1];
            const row = document.createElement('tr');

            row.innerHTML = `
                <td>${lastRow.cells[0].children[0].value}</td>
                <td>${lastRow.cells[1].children[0].value}</td>
                <td>${lastRow.cells[2].children[0].value}</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" onclick="changecolor(this, 'red')">Change color</button>
                </td>
                <td class="cellrow1">
                    <button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete row</button>
                </td>
            `;
            table.rows[table.rows.length - 1].insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', row);

            //. initialize inputs
            lastRow.cells[0].children[0].value = lastRow.cells[1].children[0].value = lastRow.cells[2].children[0].value = '';
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table</title>
    <style>
        table {
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
        tr {
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
        td {
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
    </style>
    <script defer src="myScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td>Simon</td>
        <td>Kolsch</td>
        <td>SimonK</td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" onclick="changecolor(this,'red')">Change
                color</button>
        </td>
        <td class="cellrow1">
            <button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete row</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellrow2">Noah</td>
        <td class="cellrow2">Schwarz</td>
        <td class="cellrow2">NoahS</td>
        <td class="cellrow2">
            <button type="button" onclick="changecolor(this,'red')">Change
                color</button>
        </td>
        <td class="cellrow2">
            <button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete row</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellrow3">Lukas</td>
        <td class="cellrow3">Ortlieb</td>
        <td class="cellrow3">OrLiLu</td>
        <td class="cellrow3">
            <button type="button" onclick="changecolor(this,'red')">Change
                color</button>
        </td>
        <td class="cellrow3">
            <button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete row</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellrow4">
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td class="cellrow4">
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td class="cellrow4">
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td class="cellrow4">
            <button type="button" onclick="addRow()">Create new Tablerow</button>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addRow() {
var row = table.insertRow(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
cell1.innerHTML = 'NEW CELL1';
cell2.innerHTML = 'NEW CELL2';
cell3.innerHTML = 'NEW CELL3';
cell4.innerHTML = "<button onclick= '//function'>Zeile färben</button>";
cell5.innerHTML = "<button onclick='//function'>Zeile löschen</button>";
}

addRow()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table</title>
    <style>
        table {
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
        tr {
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
        td {
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
    </style>
    <script defer src="myScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="table">
        <tr>
            <td class="cellrow1">Simon</td>
            <td class="cellrow1">Kolsch</td>
            <td class="cellrow1">SimonK</td>
            <td class="cellrow1">
                <button type="button" onclick="changecolor('cellrow1','color')">Change 
                color</button>
            </td>
            <td class="cellrow1">
                <button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete row</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="cellrow2">Noah</td>
            <td class="cellrow2">Schwarz</td>
            <td class="cellrow2">NoahS</td>
            <td class="cellrow2">
                <button type="button" onclick="changecolor('cellrow2','color')">Change 
                color</button>
            </td>
            <td class="cellrow2">
                <button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete row</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="cellrow3">Lukas</td>
            <td class="cellrow3">Ortlieb</td>
            <td class="cellrow3">OrLiLu</td>
            <td class="cellrow3">
                <button type="button" onclick="changecolor('cellrow3','color')">Change 
                color</button>
            </td>
            <td class="cellrow3">
                <button type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete row</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="cellrow4">
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td class="cellrow4">
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td class="cellrow4">
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td class="cellrow4">
                <button type="button" onclick="addRow()">Create new Tablerow</button>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it